# Procedimentos aninhados em C sendo ignorados pelo procedimento anterior

Tags: c

Estou tendo um problema no último procedimento do código a seguir, onde o procedimento receberString para fazer a comparação com outra cadastrada está sendo ignorado e pulando direto para receberEndereco.

Alguém poderia me dizer por que e como solucionar?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct enderecoStruct
{
char rua[40];
char bairro[30];
int numero;
char cep[8];
char cidade[20];
char estado[20];
} Endereco;

typedef struct CadastroPessoaStruct
{
char nome[40];
char reg[13];
char rg[10];
char telefone[11];
Endereco end;
} Pessoa;

Pessoa *clientes;
int qtdClientes, tamClientes;

void removerQuebraLinha(char *string)
{
if(string != NULL && strlen(string) > 0)
{
    short tamanho = strlen(string);
    if(string[tamanho-1] == '\n')
    {
        string[tamanho-1] = '\0';
    }
}
}

void receberString(char *string_destino, int quantidade_caracteres)
{
fgets(string_destino, quantidade_caracteres, stdin);
removerQuebraLinha(string_destino);
}

Pessoa receberCliente()
{
Pessoa p;

printf("Nome: ");
receberString(p.nome, 39);
printf ("CPF: ");
receberString(p.reg, 13);
fflush(stdin);
printf ("RG: ");
receberString(p.rg, 11);
fflush(stdin);
printf ("Telefone: ");
receberString(p.telefone, 12);
fflush(stdin);

p.end = receberEndereco();

system("cls");

sucesso();
return p;
}

Endereco receberEndereco()
{
Endereco e;

printf ("Rua: ");
receberString(e.rua, 39);
fflush(stdin);
printf ("Numero: ");
scanf("%5d", &e.numero);
fflush(stdin);
printf ("CEP: ");
receberString(e.cep, 9);
fflush(stdin);
printf ("Bairro: ");
receberString(e.bairro, 29);
printf ("Cidade: ");
receberString(e.cidade, 20);
printf ("Estado: ");
receberString(e.estado, 20);

system("cls");

sucesso();
return e;
}

void inserirCliente(Pessoa p)
{
if(qtdClientes == tamClientes)
{
    tamClientes *= 1.5;
    clientes = realloc(clientes, tamClientes*sizeof(Pessoa));
}
clientes[qtdClientes] = p;
qtdClientes++;
}

Pessoa *buscarCliente(char *cpf)
{

Pessoa *p = NULL;
int i;
for (i=0; i < qtdClientes; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(clientes[i].reg, cpf) == 0)
    {
        p = &clientes[i];
        break;
    }
}
return p;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
char cpf[13];

printf("Digite os dados do cliente: ");
inserirCliente(receberCliente);

printf("CPF do cliente cadastrado");
receberString(cpf, 13);
(buscarCliente(cpf);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Só com este trecho não tem como.

Comment: Tá faltando o `main`. Além disso, você tem um monte de `fflush(stdin)`. Isso gera comportamento indefinido, então seu programa pode, literalmente, comportar-se como quiser.